# TFS branch merged back to trunk. vbproj file name got changed

Tags: .net, tfs, merge

I merged a branch from an existing trunk and looks like all the new files in the branch came to this existing turnk as one project. Only problem is I said "copy from source" for the vbproj file and now it has the name of the file in branch. can I just rename this file and everything will be back to normal or is there some more stuff involved?

Comment: Could you clairfy what you mean by "all the new files in the branch came to this existing turnk as one project" [sic]?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're issue is here (see my comment); however:

If you rename the file *in the trunk* then it will be recorded as a change-set against the trunk as all changes you make in a TFS respository are associated with a change-set in this way, whether related to development or repository administration.  If you then intend on using your branch again you will need to forward-integrate this change-set from the trunk by doing a merge to the existing branch.  Otherwise, when you try and bring your changes back from the branch to the trunk again, you'll get a conflict.

If you're not 100% sure of the concepts of TFS - or source control in general for that matter - I'd recommend reading the [Microsoft Patterns & Practises: Team Development with TFS Guide](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSGuide) as it clearly defines the basics of branching and merging etc.